# Responsive Web pages too small on mobile device

Tags: jquery, html, css, viewport

I have a website that I have made responsive.  The website loads correctly in the browser.  However on the phone itself, the website has the correct width but the height only half the screen in Portrait mode with small fonts.  In Landscape it loads perfectly.

How can I make it fill the entire screen in portrait mode?  I am using JQuery with the hamburger menu in portrait mode only for my navigation list.  I am also using the viewport code with `content="device width"`.  If I add the `initial-scale=1`, this loads the entire website in zoomed in mode in which I have to scroll horizontally and vertically.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <!-- This add the Angular JS to the program -->  
    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script  src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script  src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script  src="js/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script  src="js/app.js"></script>

    <!-- This add the JQuery to the program -->  
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script  src="js/menu.js"></script>


    <!-- Responsive Design Viewport code -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css" media="screen and (max-width: 900px)"/>


</head>

<!-- Webcontainer  -->
<div id="webcontainer">

    <!-- Headersection outlines the header section of the webcontainer -->

  <div id="headersection">
    <div id="header-topblank-sec">
       <div id="horiznav">
          <a class="burger-menu"></a>
          <!-- Menu Items -->
          <ul> 
            <li>
               <a href="#/home">HOME</a>
               <a href="#/about">ABOUT</a>
               <a href="#/matchup">THE MATCHUP</a>
               <a href="#/vote">VOTE</a>
       <a href="#/contact">CONTACT</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
       </div>           <!-- Loads the blank color section -->


    </div>

    <div id="headerimage">
       <!-- Load the logo -->
   <div id="header-img-sec">
    <img src="img/Clash-Head-Image-alt-size.png">
        </div>
    </div>



<div id="header-botblank-sec"> 
       <!-- Loads the blank color section and subtitle-->
   <div id="clash_subtitle">
       <p><em>&quot;A Marching Band Exhibition&quot</em></p>
       </div>
    </div>


  </div>

    <!-- Websections  -->
    <div id="websections">


       <!-- Defines the Right Section of Websections -->
       <!-- <div id="rightsection"> -->
       <div id="web-body">              

         <div ng-view=""></div>
       </div>

    </div>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: can you share your body section of your code?

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: this code makes the entire website appear in zoomed in mode.  I would only be able to view it by scrolling horizontally and vertically

Comment: If you have to scroll horizontally after adding the "viewport" meta tag, then your page isn't really responsive. You need to check you code to see why this happens.

Comment: i beg to differ. The page is very responsive as the hamburger menu appears after the specified breakpoint.  It's only after adding "initial-scale=1" that I have to scroll horizontally

Answer (score 0):

To fill your page fully, you may set the container `min-height: 100vh`

Comment: would I put this in the html or css?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the main css or responsive css

Comment: Sorry, I do not know main css and responsive css that you mean, are they two css files?